# Why does @Transient annotation not working

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I understood that @Transient annotation on Spring-boot-data use for make the DB mapping ignore the annotated field.

From some reason, currently this behavior stopped work.

I don't sure if it was working, it's new feature that I'm developing.

How can I find the problem??

Also I have tried to assign to getter but the result was the same.

Here is some of the code:

```
//imports... 
//import javax.persistence.Transient;//--->also tried
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;


import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data

public class AppUser extends User{

    //...

    @Transient//the JPA should not mapping this field
    private String[] passwordCopies= new String[2];;

    @Transient
    private String excludeMe = "aaa";
    
    @Transient
    public String getExcludeMe() {
        return excludeMe;
    }

    //...

}
```

[image: DB scheme]

Comment: what version of spring boot are you using ?

Comment: First you should use JPA `@Transient`, second you shouldn't mix attribute and getters annotations in your code, and we should see all your relevant code in order to have more details about the problem.

Comment: @AndreiLisa 2.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking again, as @cнŝdk pointed out in the comments, it seems that the problem was in wrong import.

the right import should be :

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;//-->Working well
//import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;//---not working
```